# Using FastMM4, how to register leaked string?

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-2010, fastmm

With FastMM4 one can easily register a leaked pointer, but not a leaked string. Apparently the `@` operator applied to a string is not really giving us the whole string, nor is `PChar(string)`; What can I use to nicely register a leaked string?

For now I found this works:

```
FastMM4.RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(Pointer(NativeInt(PChar(StringVariable))-12));
```

But it relies on the magic number `12`, and that's version-dependent, and the code really doesn't express what's going on. I hope there's a RTL function somewhere that takes a string and gives back a pointer to the "base" of the string, or some `FastMM4` method that I overlooked.

I can pack that ugly beast of expression in a procedure like this, but I still find it hacky:

```
procedure RegisterExpectedStringLeak(const s:string);
begin
  {$IFDEF VER210}
  FastMM4.RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(Pointer(NativeInt(PChar(s))-12));
  {$ELSE}
  {$MESSAGE Fatal 'This only works on Delphi 2010'}
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

---

*This should be irrelevant for the question. Here's why I'm leaking strings:*

I'm using a caching mechanism to store certain pieces of data for the life of the application. I do not intend to free those objects, because I do need them *for the life of the application* and going through proper finalization only waists time at application shutdown. Those objects contain some string fields, so obviously those strings are "leaked".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I can think of would be:

```
function RegisterExpectedStringLeak(const S: string): Boolean;
  type
    {Have to redeclare StrRec here, because it is not in the interface section of system.pas}
    PStrRec = ^StrRec;
    StrRec = packed record
      {$ifdef CONDITIONALEXPRESSIONS}
      {$if RTLVersion >= 20}
      codePage: Word;
      elemSize: Word;
      {$ifend}
      {$endif}
      refCnt: Longint;
      length: Longint;
    end;
begin
  Result := RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(Pointer(NativeInt(PChar(S)) - SizeOf(StrRec)));
end;
```

The re-declaration of `StrRec` is copied from Delphi XE's `getmem.inc` (FastMM4) - I only added the `{$ifdef CONDITIONALEXPRESSIONS}`. I think it should be backwards-compatible with older versions of Delphi, too.

Comment: I really like the copied record declaration, it makes the `12` allot more palatable. (2 x 4 + 2 x 2 = 12). +1